# Poblem with filtering price in custom report grid in magento

Tags: grid, custom, filter, column

[image]

every time I filter for that subtotal column, it turns into admin homepage

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('icube_reportendorsement_grid');
    $this->setDefaultSort('invoice_id');
    $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
    $this->setFilterVisibility(true);
}


protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')->getCollection();
    $orderTable = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales_flat_order');
    $customerTable = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('customer_entity');



    $collection->addFieldToFilter('order.customer_id', array('neq' => NULL));
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('main_table.entity_id', array('neq' => NULL));
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('customer.group_id', 4);


    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                array('order' => $orderTable), 'order.entity_id = main_table.order_id',
                array('customer_firstname' => 'order.customer_firstname',
                        'customer_lastname' => 'order.customer_lastname',
                        'total_qty_ordered' => 'total_qty_ordered'))
                        ->joinLeft(
                array('customer' => $customerTable), 'order.customer_id = customer.entity_id',
                array('customer_email' => 'customer.email'));

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    parent::_prepareCollection();
    return $this;

}


protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $currency = (string) Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Directory_Model_Currency::XML_PATH_CURRENCY_BASE);

    $this->addColumn('customer_firstname', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('icube_report')->__('First Name'),
        'index'     => 'customer_firstname',
        'sortable'  => 'true'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('customer_lastname', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('icube_report')->__('Last Name'),
        'index'     => 'customer_lastname',
        'sortable'  => 'true'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('customer_email', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('icube_report')->__('Email'),
        'index'     => 'customer_email',
        'sortable'  => 'true'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('invoice_id', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('icube_report')->__('No. of Invoice'),
        'index'     => 'entity_id',
        'sortable'  => 'true'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('subtotal', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('icube_report')->__('Subtotal'),
        'index'  => 'subtotal',
        'type'      => 'currency',
        'currency' => $currency,
        'filter_condition_callback' => 'filter_subtotal',
    ));


    $this->addColumn('total_qty_ordered', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('icube_report')->__('Total Qty (pcs)'),
        'index'     => 'total_qty_ordered',
        'sortable'  => 'true'
    ));

    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportReportendorsementCsv', Mage::helper('icube_report')->__('CSV'));

    return parent::_prepareColumns();

}


public function getGridUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
}
```